# jQuery slideToggle() only slide to cover part of the background

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I've got clickable div's set up that users use as buttons on a webpage.  I'd like to create a "toolbox" of these "buttons" that users click on, but I'd like to have most of the buttons hidden until a user clicks a "more buttons" button (an arrow). To let the user know that the toolbox includes more buttons, I'd like to display the top half of the second row of buttons.

Is there a nifty way to do this in jQuery?

Hopefully this wireframe helps:

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: Can you provide some html code ?

Comment: nifty? just play a bit with absolute positioning in css. two panels, where the second is positioned over the first, for example if the height of the first is 100 pixels, make the css "top" property of the second set to 50px. then if you click something, animate or move the second to 100px... you will get it, try it, play a bit, and then provide us some code ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/heera/zfVF5, May be this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

or this one ;-)

http://jsfiddle.net/enxax/

Comment: Thanks for the hover idea. Heera got here first, but really awesome implementation with hover.

Comment: Hey man you deserve one vote from me for your nice work. Tyler DeWitt was fair enough.